# how to use pos in MigLayout?

Tags: miglayout

This is my code:

```
public class InfoPanel extends JPanel{
... ... ...
... ... ...

public InfoPanel(){
... ... ...
... ... ...
MigLayout lManager = new MigLayout();
setLayout(lManager);

add(lblName,new CC().pos("50", "80"));
add(txtName, new CC().pos("90","80").width("170").wrap().gap("r"));
add(lblOccupation,"pos 20 100");
add(txtOccupation,"pos 91 100,w 170,wrap,gap r");
```

and it has the right output.
but I want to use any built in code for calculate pos() for txtName, txtOccupation.
can anybody help me to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "built in code"? Usually you don't need to call methods from MigLayout. You only add the constraints as a String and MigLayout does the rest. Could you describe what you want more precicely?

Comment: Yes, for txtName(JTextField) I use pos 90 80, I manually calculate 90 for x , Is it possible without manually calculate. As example we can do it in SpringLayout. Thats all.

Comment: Do you **really** want to use absolute positioning? Because usually you just place the components relative to each other and the layoutManager does the rest. I always had bad experiences with absolute positioning because it is difficult to maintain. Describe what you want to have as result, maybe there is a better solution without absolute positioning.

Comment: Yea, you right. As you say, "Because usually you just place the components relative to each other and the layoutManager does the rest" . Can you write some code for same work as I wrote already. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, I can. But then I need more information about what you want. The things I see are 4 components at some absolute positions.

Comment: Yes, Just four components and they are in absolute positions. Sometimes, it is necessary to do specific component put in a specific place. But, we should not place them all manually(if possible). I can give you an example, like spring layout we can do  same work just use only Jlabel(lblName) position and JText( txtName) will take right place automatically(we use specific function). I am looking for such kind of features in MigLayout. Or can we do it by ourselves? If you have any idea just share with us.

Comment: For learning it, I would recommend the getting started: http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image as template:

```java
public class MigLayoutTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MigLayoutTest().start();
        }
    });
}

private void start() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 4, debug", "[][fill, grow 1][][fill, grow 4]", ""));


    //Declaration
    JLabel nameLabel, employmenLabel, ssnLabel, taxIDLabel;
    JTextField nameField, ssnField, taxIDField;
    JComboBox<String> employmentBox;
    JCheckBox checkbox;
    JButton save, cancel, upload;
    JPanel imagePlaceholder;


    //Initialization
    nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
    employmenLabel = new JLabel("Employment");
    ssnLabel = new JLabel("Social Security Number");
    taxIDLabel = new JLabel("tax ID");
    nameField = new JTextField();
    ssnField = new JTextField();
    taxIDField = new JTextField();
    save = new JButton("Save");
    cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    upload = new JButton("Upload");
    checkbox = new JCheckBox("Checkbox");
    imagePlaceholder = new JPanel();
    employmentBox = new JComboBox<String>();


    //Some editing
    imagePlaceholder.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    employmentBox.addItem("Some");
    employmentBox.addItem("items");
    employmentBox.addItem("to");
    employmentBox.addItem("fill");
    employmentBox.addItem("this");


    //Adding to contentPane
    contentPane.add(nameLabel, "alignx right");
    contentPane.add(nameField, "");
    contentPane.add(ssnLabel, "alignx right");
    contentPane.add(ssnField, "");
    contentPane.add(employmenLabel, "alignx right");
    contentPane.add(employmentBox, "");
    contentPane.add(upload, "");
    contentPane.add(imagePlaceholder, "spany 3, grow");
    contentPane.add(checkbox, "split 2");
    contentPane.add(taxIDLabel, "");
    contentPane.add(taxIDField, "wrap");

    contentPane.add(save, "");
    contentPane.add(cancel, "growx 0, wrap");



    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```